# Connect to a remote Jupyter runtime over HTTPS with Google Colab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to use Google's Colab feature to connect to a remote run-time that is configured with HTTPS. However, I only see an option to inform the port on the UI, not the protocol.

I've checked the Network panel and the website starts a WebSocket connection with `http://localhost:8888/http_over_websocket?min_version=0.0.1a3`, HTTP-style.

Full details of my setup:

- I have a public Jupyter server at `https://123.123.123.123:8888` with self-signed certificate and password authentication
- I've followed [jupyter_http_over_ws' setup](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html) on the remote
- I started the remote process with `jupyter notebook --no-browser --keyfile key.pem --certfile crt.pem --ip 0.0.0.0 --notebook-dir notebook --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com'`
- I've created a local port forwarding with `ssh -L 8888:localhost:8888 dev@123.123.123.123`
- I've turned on `network.websocket.allowInsecureFromHTTPS` on Firefox
- I've went to https://localhost:8888 and logged in

Naturally, when the UI calls `http://localhost:8888/http_over_websocket?min_version=0.0.1a3` it fails. If I manually access `https://localhost:8888/http_over_websocket?min_version=0.0.1a3` (note the extra `s`) it gets through.

I see three options to solve it:

1. Tell the UI to use secure WS connection
2. Run a proxy on my local machine to transform the HTTPS into plain HTTP
3. Turn off HTTPS on my remote

The last two I think will work, but I wouldn't like that way.
How to do #1?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Any update to this?

Answer (score 1):

Your option 1 isn't possible in colab today.

Why do you want to use HTTPS over an SSH tunnel that already encrypts forwarded traffic?

Comment: The only reason for me using HTTPS + SSH is that the Jupyter server is also publicly available outside Colab. However, I'll try starting a second Jupyter process in the server, this one only available from the SSH tunel.